# How are Clan Trophies calculated?

Tags: clash-royale

Clan trophies are not the sum of the trophies of my clan's members trophies. What is the formula used to calculate clan trophies?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clan trophies are calculated based off a weighted score of the clan's members current trophies. Depending on the rank of the member, a percentage of their trophies are added to the clan's.

Here is a table of the weights from the [Supercell website:](https://supercell.helpshift.com/a/clash-of-clans/?s=other-clan-stuff&f=how-are-clan-points-trophies-calculated&p=web)

[image: Clan trophies calculation]

> This means that the first 10 members' trophies are the most important factor in deciding the overall clan score. A clan consisting of very strong top players, with weak players in the lower ranks can still have a very good score.